# How to get items within a nested list python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am looking at this list:

```
    'In-N-Out Burger': 
        {'Burgers': 
             {'Cheeseburger - Protein® Style (Bun replaced with Lettuce) ': {'calories': 330,'carbs': 11, 'fat': 25},
              'Hamburger w/Onion ': {'calories': 390, 'carbs': 39, 'fat': 19},
              'Double-Double® w/Onion': {'calories': 670, 'carbs': 39, 'fat': 41},
              'Cheeseburger w/Mustard & Ketchup Instead of Spread': {'calories': 400, 'carbs': 41,'fat': 18},
              'Double-Double® w/Mustard & Ketchup Instead of Spread': {'calories': 590, 'carbs': 41, 'fat': 32},
              'Double-Double® - Protein® Style (Bun replaced with Lettuce) ': {'calories': 520, 'carbs': 11, 'fat': 39},
              'Hamburger - Protein® Style (Bun replaced with Lettuce) ': {'calories': 240, 'carbs': 11, 'fat': 17},
              'Hamburger w/Mustard & Ketchup Instead of Spread': {'calories': 310, 'carbs': 41, 'fat': 10},
              'Cheeseburger w/Onion ': {'calories': 480, 'carbs': 39, 'fat': 27}},
         'French Fries':
             {'French Fries ': {'calories': 395, 'carbs': 54, 'fat': 18}},
         'Shakes':
             {'Chocolate Shake ': {'calories': 590, 'carbs': 72, 'fat': 29},
              'Strawberry Shake ': {'calories': 590, 'carbs': 81, 'fat': 27},
              'Vanilla Shake ': {'calories': 580, 'carbs': 67, 'fat': 31}}},
    'Five Guys Burgers and Fries':
        {'Sandwiches':
            {'Grilled Cheese': {'calories': 470,'carbs': 41, 'fat': 26},
             'Veggie Sandwich': {'calories': 440, 'carbs': 60, 'fat': 15}},
         'Burgers': {'Little Bacon Burger': {'calories': 560, 'carbs': 39, 'fat': 33},
                     'Hamburger': {'calories': 700, 'carbs': 39, 'fat': 43},
                     'Little Hamburger': {'calories': 480, 'carbs': 39, 'fat': 26},
                     'Bacon Burger': {'calories': 780, 'carbs': 39, 'fat': 50},
                     'Cheeseburger': {'calories': 840, 'carbs': 40, 'fat': 55},
                     'Bacon Cheeseburger': {'calories': 920, 'carbs': 40, 'fat': 62}},
         'Entrees': {'Bacon Dog': {'calories': 625, 'carbs': 40, 'fat': 42},
                     'Hot Dog': {'calories': 545, 'carbs': 40, 'fat': 35}},
         'French Fries': {'One Serving of Fries approx half of regular order': {'calories': 310, 'carbs': 39, 'fat': 15},
                          'Regular Fries': {'calories': 620, 'carbs': 78, 'fat': 30},
                          'Large Fries': {'calories': 1474, 'carbs': 184, 'fat': 71}}}}
```

I am new to learning python and cannot seem to figure out how to access the information nested into the list. My end goal is to define a function that creates the most calorie-dense meal possible using exactly one item from each category.

I was using

```
rivals['In-N-Out Burger']['Burgers'] 
no_of_burgers = len(rivals['In-N-Out Burger']['Burgers'])
no_of_burgers
```

to get the total count within the list and I know

```
rivals['In-N-Out Burger']['Burgers']['Cheeseburger - Protein® Style (Bun replaced with Lettuce) ']
```

produces the output of what is listed in that nested item. I need some advice on creating a simple function to define the highest calorie-dense meal in each category. Any help would be greatly appreciated along with any pointers for a newbie to python

Comment: That is not a list. It looks like either JSON or YAML. Is this a Python dictionary you're looking at, or a text file that needs parsing?

Comment: You have nowhere a list, only dictionnaries

Comment: it is a python dictionary, sorry mixed up the 2

Comment: @newtopython The data your looking at seems like a nested dictionary but it's not. You can learn python syntax of a `dict` (dictionary) and the way to get data out of it from here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Note that your data doesn't contains `list` (represented by square brackets `[]`) you have only `dict` (key/value)

---

For a dict containing multiple items of the same meal, you may use `max` with a dedicated `key` that will retrieve the `'calories'` value

```
{'Chocolate Shake ': {'calories': 590, 'carbs': 72, 'fat': 29},
 'Strawberry Shake ': {'calories': 590, 'carbs': 81, 'fat': 27},
 'Vanilla Shake ': {'calories': 580, 'carbs': 67, 'fat': 31}}}

def max_calories_item(items: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]):
    return max(items.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['calories'])
```

Then you can iterate over your dataset, and for each restaurant compute the highest calories meal

```
for restaurant, categories in values.items():
    total_cal = 0
    menu = []
    for name, meals in categories.items():
        most_cal = max_calories_item(meals)
        total_cal += most_cal[1]['calories']
        menu.append(most_cal[0])

    print(f"At {restaurant} the highest calorie-dense meal is composed of {menu} for a total of {total_cal}cals")


At In-N-Out Burger the highest calorie-dense meal is composed of ['Double-Double® w/Onion', 'French Fries ', 'Chocolate Shake '] for a total of 1655cals
At Five Guys Burgers and Fries the highest calorie-dense meal is composed of ['Grilled Cheese', 'Bacon Cheeseburger', 'Bacon Dog', 'Large Fries'] for a total of 3489cals
```